# Rails 5: How to order models by associated model attribute, and make them distinct

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

I have a scope in rails that is supposed to order a set of conversations by the last chat message created_at attribute. 
That goes like this:

```
class Conversation < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :chat_messages, -> { order(created_at: :asc) }, dependent: :nullify do
      def last_from_user
        from_user.order("created_at ASC").last
      end

      def last_delivered_from_user
        from_user.order("delivered_at ASC").last
      end

      def last_from_agent
        from_agent.order("created_at ASC").last
      end
    end

    default_scope { joins(:chat_messages).order("chat_messages.created_at desc").distinct }
end
```

When, for example, an organization with id 4 gets a new message I expect the order to be:

```
[4,1,2,3]
```

However, what I get is:

```
[1,2,3,4]
```

if I remove the distinct method like this:

```
class Conversation < ApplicationRecord
    default_scope { joins(:chat_messages).order("chat_messages.created_at desc") }
end
```

Conversations are ordered fine, but get duplicated:
    [4,1,2,3,4]

my chat_message model looks like this:

```
    class ChatMessage < ApplicationRecord

      # Associations
      # ------------------------------------------------------------

      belongs_to :conversation
    end
```

I cannot use the 'unique' method because this would make it impossible for the pagination to work appropriately.

However, when a conversation has more than one message the 'distinct' method messes up with the order. this scope returns the conversations in the order they were created and not the order I actually need.

Comment: The bigger question is why you're getting duplicates in that join. How is the relationship with `chat_messages` defined? And how does an "organization" fit in with this? Showing the full relationships of Conversation, ChatMessages, and any other related models would help.

Comment: its a simple has_many relation_ship 

in the chat_message model I have a belongs_to reference
and in the conversation model I have a has_many relationship

Comment: Could you edit the model code into the question to make it clear, please?

Comment: I just updated it

Comment: The distinct method messes with the order the scope is supposed to return the conversations ordered by their last message, but it orders them by the first message when adding the distinct method.

Comment: When the distinct method is in place nothing is returned duplicated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we remove Rails and just look at the SQL its clearer. What you have is a classic SQL problem of trying to get a list sorted by the max or min based on a join.

You're running a query like this:

```
SELECT conversations.*
FROM conversations
INNER JOIN chat_messages
  ON chat_messages.conversation_id = conversations.id
ORDER BY chat_messages.created_at desc
```

And you will get back ***a row for every pair of conversations and chat_messages***. That's why you have duplicates.

You can't use `distinct` with this.

```
SELECT conversations.*
FROM conversations
INNER JOIN chat_messages
  ON chat_messages.conversation_id = conversations.id
ORDER BY chat_messages.created_at desc

ERROR 3065 (HY000): Expression #1 of ORDER BY clause is not in SELECT list,
references column 'test.chat_messages.created_at' which is not in SELECT list;
this is incompatible with DISTINCT
```

If you use `select distinct conversations.*, chat_messages.created_at` you're back where you started.

I'm not sure what `.distinct` is doing, but it should probably raise an exception.

---

Instead, get rid of the duplicates with `group by conversation.id`. Now that you have a grouped query you can `order by max(chat_messages.created_at) desc`.

```
select c.*
from conversations c
join chat_messages cm
  on cm.conversation_id = c.id
group by c.id
order by max(cm.created_at) desc
```

Translating this into Rails...

```
Conversations
  .joins(:chat_messages)
  .group(:id)
  .order("max(chat_messages.created_at) desc")
```